# Typescript Cannot find module imported

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I saw a lot of related questions, but none of the answers seem to work for my scenario. I have 2 files in a node.js app (node version v13.5.0), `start.ts` and `app.ts` at root, and they look like this:

start.ts:

```
import app from './app';

console.log(app);
```

app.ts:

```
const app = {};
export default app;
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "es2015"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "pretty": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": ["start.ts", "app.ts", "src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

But when I tried to use `ts-node` to run `start.ts`, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module /<project_directory>/app imported from /<project_directory>/start.ts
    at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:96:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:72:33)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:156:40)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36)
```

I've also tried adding the file extension to the import, but then it gets me the Unknown file extension ".ts" error. And it doesn't look like I will need typings since app is a simple object, but how come it is having trouble finding the module? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I found it, it was because in package.json I added `"type": "module"`